# Whoopsie error: can’t uninstall

Tags: whoopsie

I can't  uninstall whoopsie or reinstall it, I can't purge it, and I can't find the lock files. This is the screen I get when I try to uninstall it or  reinstall or upgrade.

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  whoopsie
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/22.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package whoopsie.
(Reading database ... 339533 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../whoopsie_0.2.39ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/whoopsie not found.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 100
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/whoopsie not found.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/whoopsie_0.2.39ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 100
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/whoopsie not found.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/whoopsie_0.2.39ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```